# PyInstaller fails

Tags: raspbian, python

Can anyone throw some light on why I cannot get 'pyinstaller' to execute successfully?

The installation of pyinstaller seemed to be successful but every time I run it on the simplest of scripts, it fails on message:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit-arm/run'

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to build the bootloader for Raspbian: [Building the Bootloader](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#building-the-bootloader)

The instructions for Debian/Ubuntu should work on Raspbian, too, but do not add the repository as stated, just install the packages.

Answer (score 2):

## Full Tutorial

After many hours of searching, I got this working. The answer is straightforward, but it is spread across multiple StackExchange answers and GitHub Issues. I put it all together in this tutorial, so I save some hours for the next poor soul.

### Key Takeaways

- `pip` ships PyInstaller with the incorrect architectures. You need to build it yourself for ARM (Raspberry Pi).

### Step by Step

**1. Build the bootloader**

```
git clone https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller 
# Alternatively download the zip from https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases
cd pyinstaller/bootloader
python ./waf distclean all # or python3
cd ../PyInstaller/bootloader/
ls
```

Here you should see `Linux-32bit-arm` and inside of it `run` and `run_d`

**2. Check the bootloader**

```
file Linux-32bit-arm/run

run: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=a01c65d74d7d8b483800154dcdd4a5d2aad95d5b, stripped
```

If you see the above, you are good so far. However, if you see something like `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386`, that is wrong.

**3. Copy the bootloader**

If you installed PyInstaller with `pip` inside a `venv`, then do this

```
# Replace ${CLONED_PYINSTALLER_PATH} with the path where you git cloned above
# Replace ${PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT} with the path to your project (where you have the venv)

cp -r ${CLONED_PYINSTALLER_PATH}/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit-arm ${PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT}/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/
```

If you installed with apt-get, then do this

```
# !!! Replace python3.5 with your version
cp -r ${CLONED_PYINSTALLER_PATH}/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit-arm /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader
```

### Debugging

Issue

```
SystemError: objcopy Failure: objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `$FILE`
```

Check

```
`file dist/$FILE`
```

If it does not say `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM [...]`, but instead says Intel or x86, the PyInstaller tries to use the incorrect bootloader. If you executed all steps above, try renaming the `Linux-32bit-arm` to just `Linux-32bit`. That seems to have worked for [this user](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2848)

---

Issue

```
gcc not found
```

Solution

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the point made by [S.Spieker](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/14396/s-spieker) in [his answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19372/pyinstaller-fails#answer-19390)... I suspect that the path for the compilation of the bootloader is wrong for your platform.

Rename the directory, as mentioned in the forum, [Pyinstaller missing Linux-32bit-arm/run](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/14396/s-spieker):

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader
sudo mv Linux-32bit Linux-32bit-arm
```